# Integrating sentences with java

Tags: java, string, syntax

If I have 2 sentences:

```
String code1 = "XXXji X9 XX22 Xs dXXXd i l9XX bXX45.";

String code2 = "hello my name is david i like bread.";
```

Basically, one scrambled and one not (each word has the same number of characters)

How would I conclude this:

```
String answer = "XXXlo Xy XXme Xs dXXXd i liXX bXXad.";
```

I would have `code1` and `code2` handy, I'm not trying to decrypt anything, just integrate the strings.

Comment: What have you tried, so far? Show us some code. Just an idea how you can do it - convert your strings to char arrays -> iterate over these char arrays -> replace characters in the second char array whenever you have 'X' in the first array.

Comment: What is the logic to replace small chars and digits with other string char with same position ? or except X you are replacing every thing from other string char with same position?

Comment: Converting to char arrays is exactly what I've done, but this code is to be utilized a lot so I am looking for the more efficient way of converting.

Comment: @JackSmith You can try with StringBuilder class for constructing result string from string code1

Answer (score 0):

You can try with StringBuilder as follow:

```
public class StringConverter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String code1 = "XXXji X9 XX22 Xs dXXXd i l9XX bXX45.";
    String code2 = "hello my name is david i like bread.";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(code2);
    for(int i = 0; i < code1.length(); i++) {
        char c1 = code1.charAt(i);
        if (c1 == 'X') {
            result.replace(i, i+1, "X");
        }

    }
    System.out.println("String answer is");
    System.out.println(result);        
}
}
```

Output

```
String answer is
XXXlo Xy XXme Xs dXXXd i liXX bXXad.
```

Hope this solution work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This code should return what your asking for:

```
char[] template = code1.toCharArray();
char[] content = code1.toCharArray();

if(template.length == content.length){

    char[] newArray = new char[template.length]; 

        for(int i = 0; i < template.length; i++){
            if(template[i] != 'X'){
                newArray[i] = content[i];
            } else{
                newArray[i] = 'X';
            }
        }   

return newArray;
```

Any other utility would just be using something similar to this algorithm